# How to create a 100% width table that shows scrollbars on itself rather than on the document

Tags: css

If I use a fixed width and overflow: auto then I can get scrollbars but I can't use the available width of the screen.

If I use no width then the table uses all available width but forces the document itself to have scrollbars when the browser window is too narrow.

How can I get the best of both worlds? Is there a non-javascript solution?

PS Did I mention this needs to work in IE6 too? :-)

To clarify: The table is 100% the width of it's container (in this case a table cell but don't worry - I've got an official permit) rather than 100% of the browser width. I want it to have fluid width and height but if the browser window is too narrow to contain it I want the table to have scrollbars rather than the document.

Comment: How would the table having scrollbars differ from the body having scrollbars? What would change visually?

Comment: The table is much smaller than the document. I want the user to scroll within the table, not scroll the whole document.

Comment: Ah. I just realised why you asked. The table is 100% of a container - not the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using a div, with a height, and put the table inside that div.  that div will have `overflow: auto`.

Comment: Why is the height important? (I don't know the number of rows so specifying a height would be tricky). I've just noticed that the 'overflow' WAS applied to a container DIV so the only difference to your suggestion is the height.

Comment: andybak: I assume that without the height specified, the div will just stretch according to its children's size. If you don't want a set height, try <code>max-height</code>.